# Trying to figure out how to to bring the total score back up to main to print out. It is being displayed but not stored in the variable

Tags: java, methods, display

I'm trying to figure out how to to bring the total score back up to main to print out. It is being displayed but not stored in the variable

This is the most important method in my code.I am trying to figure out how to return the final score for each player even though these methods are nested. This is supposed to be like the game Price Is Right. There are three players all spinning a wheel trying to get as close to 100 as they can. If they go over they are out of the game. I didn't include my main method, but I have just been calling they methid player() for each person. I have gotten this approach to work, I just need to figure out how to send values up to main.

```
public static int player() {

    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in); //asks user if they are ready
    String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
    if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
        int total = 0;
        total += spinWheel(); //method to spin wheel
        if (total < 100) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to spin again?"); //if < 100 they have the chance to spin again
            userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
            if (userInput.equals("yes")) { /asks them if they want to spin
            total += spinWheelTwice();
            System.out.println("Final Score is: " + total); //adds to the earlier spin    

            } // I want to store the final score in a variable that I can pass back up to main
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ignore the random letter, it wouldn't let me post with adding more details

Comment: That means you need to add details

Comment: Declare `total` before your `if` block, then `return total;` after the if block ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried returning total, but it's undefined ??

Comment: @Berger what should I declare it too???

Comment: when I try to return total, back up into the main, it says unreachable. Does this have something to do with the fact that my methods are nested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your calling method (`main` I think you use), just declare a variable for the return from `player()`, i.e. `int total = player();`.

And in `player()`, you need to return the amount to the calling method. But first, I'd declare `total` at the very top of `player()`.

You simply need to return the `total` variable at the end of the block.

```
public static int player() {
    int total = 0; 
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
    if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
        total += spinWheel();
        if (total < 100) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to spin again?");
            userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
            if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
                total += spinWheelTwice();
                System.out.println("Final Score is: " + total);
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

You can then use the `total` variable in `main` however you choose.

**Edit:**

As per comment below, if you wish to advise user they are out of the game if the total is < 100, perhaps consider putting in an `if...else` where you advise the total score:

```
if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
    total += spinWheelTwice();
    if (total < 100) {
         System.out.println("You are out of the game");
    } else {
         System.out.println("Final Score is: " + total);
    }
}
```

You also may need it, if the user doesn't enter "yes" a second time (and maybe even if they don't the first time), but if so, then put it an `else` clause to the second nested `if`.

Example:

```
public static int player() {
    int total = 0;
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
    if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
        total += spinWheel();
        if (total < 100) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to spin again?");
            userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
            if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
                total += spinWheelTwice();
                if (total < 100) {
                    System.out.println("You are out of the game");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Final Score is: " + total);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("You are out of the game");
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to return total inside the if statements. Returning it once at the end of the method, in this case, is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this helped greatly! Lets say I wanted to add one more if statement that says if ( total < 100) { System.out.println("You are out of the game.") } How would I return this value, and where would I place it in the code. I keep receiving errors that say it is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was that you declared the `total` variable inside the `if` scope, meaning that the variable `total` was unreachable from outside that scope. You need to declare `total` outside the scope if you want to return it.

```
if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
    int total = 0;
    // ...
} 
return total; // this is unreachable
```

should have been

```
int total = 0;
if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
    // ...
}
return total;
```

To answer your question,

```
public static int player() {
    System.out.println("Are you ready? (yes/no)");
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
    int total = 0;
    if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
        total = spinWheel();
        System.out.println("You spun " + total);
        if (total < 100) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to spin again?");
            userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
            if (userInput.equals("yes")) {
                total += spinWheelTwice();
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}


public static void main(String... args) {
    int total = YourClassName.player();
    System.out.println("Final Score is: " + total);
}
```

*Code like this brings back good memories*